# how to select multiple rows in table via checkbox and pass these values to another table

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I want to select multiple rows in a table via checkboxes and store these values in another table.I have almost done. But problem is that when I select multiple rows and get these values via array. It only fetch single value. I want all selected values. Please help me in this regard. My code is given below.

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="add_exam_quiz.php" role="form" id="form1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="quiz_question[<?php echo  $question_no; ?>]" value="<?php echo  $question_no; ?>">
      <?php echo  $question_no; ?> 
    </td>
</form>
</tr>

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" form="form1">
```

I expect an array with all checked values. But I got single value.

Comment: You have invalid HTML - `form` tag is closed before `tr`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all the checkboxes with the same name like this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="quiz_question[]" value="<?php echo  $question_no; ?>"> <?php echo  $question_no; ?> </td>
```

then in PHP:

```
<?php

   $quiz_question = $_POST['quiz_question'];

   foreach ($quiz_question as $question=>$value) {
             echo $value."<br />";
        }

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked more than one checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give same NAME for all check box options. If you give different NAME it won't work.

Comment: I gave same same but still out single value.I have to use submit button outside the form..this might be causing trouble

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, if you are submitting the form with JS. Otherwise yes, that will be a problem if submit button is outside the form closing tag

Comment: how can I do that with JS ?.Please can u help me.